# Perl Map Method

Tags: perl, dictionary

Need to know this,

```
Open File;
map{ chomp; $isword{uc join "", sort /./g}.= "$_+" } <File>;
```

Wants to know what this maps does and What it will return.. Couldnt understand sort and why uc join "".

File used for this program contains wordlist.

Some one help please..

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Answer (score 5):

What it returns is moot, since it's discarded. That makes it a weird use of `map`. One would normally write

```
for (<File>) { chomp; $isword{uc join "", sort /./g}.= "$_+"; }
```

which is waste of memory compared to

```
while (<File>) { chomp; $isword{uc join "", sort /./g} .= "$_+"; }
```

For each line it encounters, it normalises the characters that form the line.

```
apple becomes AELPP
orange becomes AEGNOR
art becomes ART
rat becomes ART
tar becomes ART
etc
```

It uses that normalised form as the key to a hash, and stores the line at that key.

```
$isword{AELPP} = 'apple+';
$isword{AEGNOR} = 'orange+';
$isword{ART} = 'art+rat+tar+';
```

Assuming each line is a word, it allows one to quickly lookup anagrams of a word.

```
sub find_anagrams { split /\+/, $isword{uc join "", sort /./g} // '' }
```

Comment: thank you. could you please explain this part of code alone, uc join "", sort /./g. I am not getting how it does normalization.

Comment: Uppercase the string formed by joining the sorted characters of `$_`.

Comment: You say "weird", I say "symptomatic of an unhealthy fascination with using the wrong language construct, sometimes called 'Lookit, I can use map for this!' syndrome". `</bitter>`